# Ngrx: How to subscribe to a few actions in component?

Tags: observable, action, ngrx, ngrx-store

I need to subscribe to a few actions and make them as one, otherwise it causing duplication pop up messages.

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin([
      this.actions.pipe(ofType(userActions.updateUserFail)),
      this.actions.pipe(ofType(brandActions.updateBrandFail)),
    ]).subscribe(() => {
      this.toastr.error(userInfoFailMsg);
    });
  }
```

But this does not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForkJoin only emits values if all source observables complete, see https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin.

Actions are per definition a never ending stream. I think what you want is:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge
Like this:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    merge([
      this.actions.pipe(ofType(userActions.updateUserFail)),
      this.actions.pipe(ofType(brandActions.updateBrandFail)),
    ]).subscribe(userInfoFailMsg => {
      this.toastr.error(userInfoFailMsg);
    });
  }
```

With actions, this actually should work as well:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
      this.actions.pipe(ofType(
         userActions.updateUserFail, 
         brandActions.updateBrandFail)
      ).subscribe(userInfoFailMsg => {
      this.toastr.error(userInfoFailMsg);
    });
  }
```